# hibernate entries stopping on own

Tags: oracle, hibernate, websphere

I have an application in jsf 1.2 , richfaces and hibernate with oracle 11gR2 at the back end. Data entry in application suddenly stops after like hundred entries. No exception generated by jsf application. Once application is stopped at the websphere and restarted. the data entry from jsf application again starts. and again after 100 or so entries. entry stops. which is resolved by stopping and restarting application on websphere.

I just want to ask where to look for the problem. Any vague idea or starting point would be gold for me.

Comment: Wen application stops try do the thread dump, you will see where the application is waiting, maybe it will give you some hints.

Comment: which i can do using IBM Thread Dump Analyzer is that right?

Comment: Yes, thats the correct tool. If you are on Linux/AIX you can generate dump using `kill -3 pid`. Otherwise you need to write jython script (or if in WAS 8.5 use admin console). See here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/txml_dump.html?lang=en

Comment: if u can add ur comment as answer. i will select it as correct as that was really what i was looking for. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To better troubleshoot application that hangs you can generate thread dump and analyze it with IBM Thread Dump Analyzer.

If you are on Linux/AIX you can generate dump using kill -3 pid. Otherwise you need to write jython script (or if in WAS 8.5 use admin console).

See also:

- [Dumping threads in server processes using scripting](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/txml_dump.html?lang=en)
- [Collecting Java dumps and core files using the administrative console](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/ttrb_dumpcore.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5&lang=en)
- [MustGather: Performance, hang, or high CPU issues on Windows](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21111364)
- [IBM Thread and Monitor Dump Analyzer for Java](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=2245aa39-fa5c-4475-b891-14c205f7333c)